# Drupal External Authentication

Tags: php, drupal, curl, authentication

I have a cURL PHP script which is able to validate a username/password against the external source.

What is the best way to integrate this as a login requirement for (select) users in Drupal?

Comment: Those *select* users already exist as 'normal' drupal users? If so, should the external authentication happen 'additionally to' or 'instead of' the standard drupal authentication?

Comment: Indeed, the select users are normal drupal users. The idea would be to add the external authentication as a login requirement for a role.

Answer (score 3):

To start with, you could look at the code of the OpenID module that comes with Drupal 6 - creating a new module based on this code should get you 90% of the way. It allows existing users to associate OpenIDs with their accounts, and it sounds like you'd need to do something similar from your reply to Henrik.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you can add a validation function to the form with ID `user_login` to verify if the additional conditions are verified. If you do this, remember to add your validation function with `array_unshift()`, or the user will be authenticated the same.